# How to draw jquery bar chart

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, charts, bar-chart

i have Struts2 project where i have values in database and i successfully retrieved those values from my database to the jsp table. Now i want to show those values in the "Jquery bar chart" instead of showing it on the table. I searched in google for it but didnt convince with any answer..some of them are using ajax(json) etc..will it be possible only with jquery and jsp or java?. Please guide me or give me any related link. Thanks in advance.  Here is my code which I am using to retrieve from the database and showing it on the jsp page in tables.
My action class looks like the below

```
package com.rajesh.action;

import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;



public class FebruaryAction {

List abc=  new ArrayList();
List abc1= new ArrayList();
List abc2= new ArrayList();
List abc3= new ArrayList();
List abc4= new ArrayList();
List abc5= new ArrayList();
List abc6= new ArrayList();
List abc7= new ArrayList();






public List getAbc() {
return abc;
}


public void setAbc(List abc) {
this.abc = abc;
}



public List getAbc1() {
return abc1;
}


public void setAbc1(List abc1) {
this.abc1 = abc1;
}



public List getAbc2() {
return abc2;
}


public void setAbc2(List abc2) {
this.abc2 = abc2;
}



public List getAbc3() {
return abc3;
}


public void setAbc3(List abc3) {
this.abc3 = abc3;
}




public List getAbc4() {
return abc4;
}


public void setAbc4(List abc4) {
this.abc4 = abc4;
}


public List getAbc5() {
return abc5;
}


public void setAbc5(List abc5) {
this.abc5 = abc5;
}


public List getAbc6() {
return abc6;
}


public void setAbc6(List abc6) {
this.abc6 = abc6;
}



public List getAbc7() {
return abc7;
}


public void setAbc7(List abc7) {
this.abc7 = abc7;
}


public String execute() throws Exception {

Connection con = GetCon.getCon();
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate,  ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >= '2013-02-01' AND OrderDate <= '2013-02-28' AND MarketPlace= 'AUK' GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace") ;   

while(resultset.next()){
String marketplace = resultset.getString(1);
String orderdate = resultset.getString(2);
Double datamount = resultset.getDouble(3);
Integer count= resultset.getInt(4);
Double result=resultset.getDouble(5);

ReportClass a = new ReportClass();
a.setMarketplace(marketplace);
a.setOrderdate(orderdate);
a.setDataamount(datamount);
a.setCount(count);
a.setResult(result);
abc.add(a);


}

Statement statement1 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet resultset1 = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >= '2013-02-01' AND OrderDate <= '2013-02-28' AND MarketPlace= 'AUS' GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace") ;  

while(resultset1.next()){
String marketplace = resultset1.getString(1);
String orderdate = resultset1.getString(2);
Double datamount = resultset1.getDouble(3);
Integer count= resultset1.getInt(4);
Double result=resultset1.getDouble(5);

ReportClass a = new ReportClass();
a.setMarketplace(marketplace);
a.setOrderdate(orderdate);
a.setDataamount(datamount);
a.setCount(count);
a.setResult(result);
abc1.add(a);
}

Statement statement2 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet resultset2 = statement2.executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >= '2013-02-01' AND OrderDate <= '2013-02-28' AND MarketPlace= 'ADE' GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace") ;  

while(resultset2.next()){
String marketplace = resultset2.getString(1);
String orderdate = resultset2.getString(2);
Double datamount = resultset2.getDouble(3);
Integer count= resultset2.getInt(4);
Double result=resultset2.getDouble(5);

ReportClass a = new ReportClass();
a.setMarketplace(marketplace);
a.setOrderdate(orderdate);
a.setDataamount(datamount);
a.setCount(count);
a.setResult(result);
abc2.add(a);
}

Statement statement3 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet resultset3 = statement3.executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >= '2013-02-01' AND OrderDate <= '2013-02-28' AND MarketPlace= 'Ebay' GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace") ; 

while(resultset3.next()){
String marketplace = resultset3.getString(1);
String orderdate = resultset3.getString(2);
Double datamount = resultset3.getDouble(3);
Integer count= resultset3.getInt(4);
Double result=resultset3.getDouble(5);

ReportClass a = new ReportClass();
a.setMarketplace(marketplace);
a.setOrderdate(orderdate);
a.setDataamount(datamount);
a.setCount(count);
a.setResult(result);
abc3.add(a);
}

Statement statement4 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet resultset4 = statement4.executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >= '2013-02-01' AND OrderDate <= '2013-02-28' AND MarketPlace= 'Play' GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace") ; 

while(resultset4.next()){
String marketplace = resultset4.getString(1);
String orderdate = resultset4.getString(2);
Double datamount = resultset4.getDouble(3);
Integer count= resultset4.getInt(4);
Double result=resultset4.getDouble(5);

ReportClass a = new ReportClass();
a.setMarketplace(marketplace);
a.setOrderdate(orderdate);
a.setDataamount(datamount);
a.setCount(count);
a.setResult(result);
abc4.add(a);
}
Statement statement5 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet resultset5 = statement5.executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >= '2013-02-01' AND OrderDate <= '2013-02-28' AND MarketPlace= 'Abe' GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace") ;  

while(resultset5.next()){
String marketplace = resultset5.getString(1);
String orderdate = resultset5.getString(2);
Double datamount = resultset5.getDouble(3);
Integer count= resultset5.getInt(4);
Double result=resultset5.getDouble(5);

ReportClass a = new ReportClass();
a.setMarketplace(marketplace);
a.setOrderdate(orderdate);
a.setDataamount(datamount);
a.setCount(count);
a.setResult(result);
abc5.add(a);
}

Statement statement6 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet resultset6 = statement6.executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >= '2013-02-01' AND OrderDate <= '2013-02-28' AND MarketPlace= 'ACA' GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace") ;  

while(resultset6.next()){
String marketplace = resultset6.getString(1);
String orderdate = resultset6.getString(2);
Double datamount = resultset6.getDouble(3);
Integer count= resultset6.getInt(4);
Double result=resultset6.getDouble(5);


ReportClass a = new ReportClass();
a.setMarketplace(marketplace);
a.setOrderdate(orderdate);
a.setDataamount(datamount);
a.setCount(count);
a.setResult(result);
abc6.add(a);
}



Statement statement8 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet resultset8 = statement8.executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >= '2013-02-01' AND OrderDate <= '2013-02-28' AND MarketPlace= 'AFR' GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace") ;  

while(resultset8.next()){
String marketplace = resultset8.getString(1);
String orderdate = resultset8.getString(2);
Double datamount = resultset8.getDouble(3);
Integer count= resultset8.getInt(4);
Double result=resultset8.getDouble(5);

ReportClass a = new ReportClass();
a.setMarketplace(marketplace);
a.setOrderdate(orderdate);
a.setDataamount(datamount);
a.setCount(count);
a.setResult(result);
abc7.add(a);
}
return "success";


}}
```

My ReportClass.java

```
package com.rajesh.action;

public class ReportClass {

String marketplace;
String orderdate;
Double dataamount;
Integer count;
Double result;



public Double getResult() {
return result;
}
public void setResult(Double result) {
this.result = result;
}

public Integer getCount() {
return count;
}
public void setCount(Integer count) {
this.count = count;
}
public String getMarketplace() {
return marketplace;
}
public void setMarketplace(String marketplace) {
this.marketplace = marketplace;
}
public String getOrderdate() {
return orderdate;
}
public void setOrderdate(String orderdate) {
this.orderdate = orderdate;
}
public Double getDataamount() {
return dataamount;
}
public void setDataamount(Double dataamount) {
this.dataamount = dataamount;
}




}
```

My February.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*,javax.*" %>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page import="com.rajesh.action.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org     /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>February</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Report for February</h1>





<body>




<table border="1" >
<tr>
<th>Market</th>
<th>Feb-01</th>
<th>Feb-02</th>
<th>Feb-03</th>
<th>Feb-04</th>
<th>Feb-05</th>
<th>Feb-06</th>
<th>Feb-07</th>
<th>Feb-08</th>
<th>Feb-09</th> 
<th>Feb-10</th>
<th>Feb-11</th>
<th>Feb-12</th>
<th>Feb-13</th>
<th>Feb-14</th>
<th>Feb-15</th>
<th>Feb-16</th>
<th>Feb-17</th>
<th>Feb-18</th>
<th>Feb-19</th>
<th>Feb-20</th>
<th>Feb-21</th>
<th>Feb-22</th>
<th>Feb-23</th>
<th>Feb-24</th>
<th>Feb-25</th>
<th>Feb-26</th>
<th>Feb-27</th>
<th>Feb-28</th>
</tr>

<tr>

<td rowspan="3">AUK</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc}" var="item">
<td>${item.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc}" var="item">
<td>${item.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc}" var="item">
<td>${item.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">AUS</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc1}" var="item1">
<td>${item1.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc1}" var="item1">
<td>${item1.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc1}" var="item1">
<td>${item1.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">ADE</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc2}" var="item2">
<td>${item2.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc2}" var="item2">
<td>${item2.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc2}" var="item2">
<td>${item2.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">Ebay</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc3}" var="item3">
<td>${item3.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>


<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc3}" var="item3">
<td>${item3.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc3}" var="item3">
<td>${item3.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">Play</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc4}" var="item4">
<td>${item4.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc4}" var="item4">
<td>${item4.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc4}" var="item4">
<td>${item4.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">Abe</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc5}" var="item5">
<td>${item5.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc5}" var="item5">
<td>${item5.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc5}" var="item5">
<td>${item5.result}</td> 
</c:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">ACA</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc6}" var="item6">
<td>${item6.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc6}" var="item6">
<td>${item6.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc6}" var="item6">
<td>${item6.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">AFR</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc7}" var="item7">
<td>${item7.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc7}" var="item7">
<td>${item7.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc7}" var="item7">
<td>${item7.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) should do all the charting you need using jQuery.

Comment: but that is javascript chart isnt it..? i need jquery chart bro.

Comment: it is jQuery! Check out their documentation. And not sure what you mean here, because jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: okay. alright..i may be wrong because the fact that i just came out from engineering college and working on project without any prior training..:)..i will see to it..  and i ll be back if i find it confusing.

Comment: None of the place they mentioned it is jquery, all they are telling it is javascript. and I dont even see one single jquery files.

Comment: jquery itself doesn't do any charting. jQuery is just a set of convenience wrappers over JavaScript.  Do a Google search with 'jQuery Charting Libraries' and see what you get. :)

Comment: @lakshmana Kumar. I tried that but it gives me group of folders, I dont what to with that group of folders with js files.

Comment: It took me one hour to post this question but the replies that i am getting is not that helpful except the above two. Please help me out.its urgent.

Comment: well that is because you seem very confused. You really need to read up on basics of JavaScript and jQuery.  I already mentioned that Highcharts is a extremely popular charting library out there and will do everything you want in the question you posted. If you want help in setting up your javascript libraries and how to use them, as k a separate, simplified and to the point question along with code example of what you have tried.  If possible when asking JavaScript question try and make a JsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) so people can help you

Comment: @user2470723 If it's urgent then do the work yourself--relying on volunteers to figure out your task(s) and question(s) isn't particularly efficient. There are many jQuery and JavaScript charting libraries available; pick one.

Comment: @Dave Sorry dont get me wrong..i clearly mentioned except who answered my question.